# Modify Wordpress plugin?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a third-party WP plugin which, although no longer updated, still works fine - and for which I've not been able to find an alternative.

It's '[Zajax](https://wordpress.org/plugins/zajax-ajax-navigation/)' - which ajax-loads internal pages... thus enabling a streaming-radio audio-player to be fixed to the viewport-base, with continuous play throughout page-changes.

However, it appears to require absolute urls - on root-relative urls it reloads the whole page (and thus stops continuous-play).

This is a hindrance, because I normally use root-relative urls - and hence sometimes forget to ensure that all internal urls are absolute rather than root-relative.

I want to modify, so that it'll work with root-relative urls - but don't know enough to do this.

Comment: if you had technical issue, perhaps reporting that problem to the proper owner through wordpress plugin page or [github](https://github.com/onigetoc/Zajax-Wordpress-ajax-navigation) will do better rather than asking on Stackoverflow..

Comment: @Bagus Tesa As mentioned... the plugin is no longer updated,and so the developer is understandably uninterested. (And, when the plugin was still being updated, I'd asked but not received an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually using root-relative URL-s is not good idea, but if it is comfortable for you, then use small jQuery snippet which may help you with the problem.

```
jQuery("a").each(function(){
if (jQuery(this).attr("href").indexOf("http")==-1){
jQuery(this).attr("href","https://yourwebsiteurl.com/"+jQuery(this).attr("href"));
}
});
```

You can put this code to footer area of your website, it will detect root-related links and convert them to normal links. (without changing anything at your backend, of course)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that seems to sort the issue. Much appreciated. From my relatively little understanding of this, I assume it works by prepending 'https://yourwebsiteurl.com' to the root-relative url. For years I've used root-relative - quicker/easier when coding/writing content... so I'm interested why you advise they're not a good idea.